# Single bar barchart in ggplot2, R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following data and code:

```
> ddf
  var1 var2
1   aa   73
2   bb   18
3   cc    9
> 
> dput(ddf)
structure(list(var1 = c("aa", "bb", "cc"), var2 = c(73L, 18L, 
9L)), .Names = c("var1", "var2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
> 
> 
> ggplot(ddf,aes(x=var1, y=var2, fill=var1))+ geom_bar(width=1, stat='identity')
```

This creates a barchart with 3 bars. How can I create a single stacked bar from this data. I want to have all these 3 bars stacked on top of each other rather than being separate bars.

Comment: You can't specify an x-position and ask them to be stacked (for obvious reasons...)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This does what you're looking for:

```
ggplot(ddf, aes(1, var2, fill=var1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

You can't specify different x positions and asked them to be stacked at the same time. You have to specify that they're on the same x-position in order for them to be on top of each other.

Comment: You don't really need to repeat the 1 in the `aes`, ie `aes(x=1, y=var2, fill=var1))` should be fine.

Comment: I could not make out what to put for x=?  Even better than putting 1, I find putting a character or string like 'VAR' looks good. The 'VAR' is printed twice but it can be made to be printed once by adding +labs(x="") .