# Plot average of values in single plot

Tags: r

I want to plot single bar in a graph so it would look like picture below

[image]

I created test data and calculate its mean.

```
value <- c(99,44,100,120,88)
value_mean <- mean(value)
```

And plot them using below code

```
barplot(value_mean, horiz=T, width=30, cex.names=0.5 ,ylim=c(0,200), col="red")
```

Buth the output is not even close.

[image]

I've also looked at this links
[Single bar barchart in ggplot2, R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771792/single-bar-barchart-in-ggplot2-r)
[R Barplot with one bar - how to plot correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465438/r-barplot-with-one-bar-how-to-plot-correctly)

So my output should be something like the first picture. I was thinking that could solve ggplot.

Comment: You need to set the xlim not the ylim

Comment: If i do this, than my graph looks like I positioned it vertically.

Comment: make the plotting window shorter: `x11(height = 2)`

Comment: If everything else fails, construct it manually in the veins of `par(mar = c(12, 2, 12, 2));plot(0, type="n", ylim=c(-1, 1), xlim=c(0, 200), yaxt="n", bty = "n", ylab=NA, xlab="label");rect(0, -.7, value_mean, .7, col="red", border=NA)
`.

Comment: @lukeA, how would you add label of mean value like value 88 in first picture? I've tried using text(value_mean,cex=3,pos=3) but that doesn't help. And also how to add sequence from 0:200 like in the first picture?

Comment: `text(value_mean, 0, pos=4, label=value_mean)`. What sequence? For custom axis ticks, use `axes=F` in `plot` and e.g. `axis(1, at=seq(0, 200, 20))` afterwards.

Comment: Sequence of scale x so values on x axis will be labeled 0, 40, 80,120,160,200. For example when I'am using ggplot I set sequence by:scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(min(25), max(75), by = 10), limits=c(25,75)

Comment: `axis(1, at=seq(0, 200, 40))`

Comment: Thx. Could you please post your answer so I could do an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything else fails, you can draw a rectangle like this:

```
par(mar = c(12, 2, 12, 2))
plot(0, type="n", ylim=c(-1, 1), xlim=c(0, 200), axes = F, bty = "n",ylab="", xlab="label")
rect(0, -.7, value_mean, .7, col="red", border=NA)
text(value_mean, 0, pos=4, label=value_mean)
axis(1, at=seq(0, 200, by=40))
```

[image]